# Passing argument to a psql procedural script

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a loop command script on `psql`that looks like this:

### script.sql

```
DO $$DECLARE
    data_rec RECORD;
    r RECORD;
    r2 RECORD;
BEGIN
select mytables.data_id into data_rec from mytables where id = :arg1;

    FOR r IN select * from
    (select * from ...)
    LOOP
        FOR r2 IN select * from
        (...)
              LOOP
            ......
          END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

And I want to pass `arg1` as a argument from the command line:

```
psql -h db.server.com -f script.sql -v arg1=1234 > foo.out
```

But I keep getting a syntax error at `where id = :arg1`, so I'm out of ideas how to pass a simple parameter to this script. Suggestions welcome

Answer (score 3):

There are few possibilities, how to do it. Anonymous block is relative strongly isolated from client environment, so parametrisation is not intuitive - but it is not hard work.

You can use a server side session variables. These variables are accessible from both environments.

```
postgres=# \set txt Ahoj
postgres=# set myvars.txt to :'txt'; -- fill server side variable
SET
postgres=# do $$ begin raise notice '%', current_setting('myvars.txt'); end;$$;
NOTICE:  Ahoj
DO
```

Little bit more complex example

```
bash-4.1$ cat test.sh
echo "
set myvars.msgcount TO :'msgcount'; 
DO \$\$ 
BEGIN 
  FOR i IN 1..current_setting('myvars.msgcount')::int LOOP 
    RAISE NOTICE 'Hello';
  END LOOP; 
END \$\$" | psql postgres -v msgcount=$1


bash-4.1$ sh test.sh 10
SET
Time: 0.935 ms
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
NOTICE:  Hello
DO
Time: 1.709 ms
```

Comment: I see your point (on my deleted answer) - specifically in the case of a function body, it's not parsed as an expression that you can concatenate strings in, so you can't `$$ ... '$$ || :var || $$' ... $$` it.

Comment: @CraigRinger I am thinking, so your solution is possible, but I don't prefer it - server side variables based design is more clean, and automatically safe against SQL injection. Probably there are not a problem with classic attacks, but can be problem with some specific data that contains apostrophes or some other special chars.

Comment: To use *server side session variables* (aka *customized options*) in Postgres 9.1 or earlier one must set **custom_variable_classes** option in *postgresql.conf*.