# Use variable set by psql meta-command inside of DO block

Tags: postgresql, session-variables, dynamic-sql, psql, postgresql-9.4

Here's what I would like to do:

```
\set values foo,bar,baz

DO $$
DECLARE
    value  TEXT;
    values TEXT[] := string_to_array(:'values', ',');
BEGIN
    FOREACH value IN ARRAY values LOOP
        raise notice 'v: %', value;
    END LOOP;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Which results in the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
> SELECT string_to_array(:'values', ',') INTO values...
>                        ^
> ```

Here's the solution I have currently, but it feels hacky:

```
\set values foo,bar,baz

PREPARE get_values AS SELECT string_to_array(:'values', ',');

DO $$
DECLARE
    value  TEXT;
    values TEXT[];
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'EXECUTE get_values' INTO values;

    FOREACH value IN ARRAY values LOOP
        raise notice 'v: %', value;
    END LOOP;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer

[**`DO`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) expects a *string literal* with PL/pgSQL code (unless you declare a different PL). Symbols are not substituted inside strings in psql.
You could concatenate the whole string into a psql variable and *then* execute it.

- [How to concatenate psql variables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21131/3684)

Pretty multi-line format is not possible, because ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)):

> But in any case, the arguments of a meta-command cannot continue
> beyond the end of the line.

Simple example:

```
test=# \set value foo
test=# \set do 'BEGIN\n   RAISE NOTICE ''v: %'', ' :'value' ';\nEND'
test=# DO :'do';
NOTICE:  v: foo
```

Replace line breaks with `\n` (or remove them if you don't care for pretty format). Based on this adapted code:

```sql
DO
'
DECLARE
   _val  text;
   _vals text[] := string_to_array(>>values<<, '','');
BEGIN
   FOREACH _val IN ARRAY _vals
   LOOP
     RAISE NOTICE ''v: %'', _val;
   END LOOP;
END
'
```

It looks like this:

```
test=# \set do 'DECLARE\n   _val  text;\n   _vals text[] := string_to_array(' :'values' ', '','');\nBEGIN\n   FOREACH _val IN ARRAY _vals\n   LOOP\n     RAISE NOTICE ''v: %'', _val;\n   END LOOP;\nEND'
test=# DO :'do';
NOTICE:  v: foo
NOTICE:  v: bar
NOTICE:  v: baz
DO
```

I added **bold** emphasis to the variable to make it easier to spot.

Related answer by @Pavel (ab)using a [server session variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html):

- [Referring to session variables (\set var='value') from PL/PGSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868514/referring-to-session-variables-set-var-value-from-pl-pgsql/28871424#28871424)

### Alternative solutions

#### Prepared statement

Your current solution doesn't look that bad. I would simplify:

```sql
PREPARE get_values AS SELECT * FROM regexp_split_to_table(:'values', ',');

DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _val text;
BEGIN
   FOR _val IN EXECUTE
      'EXECUTE get_values'
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'v: %', _val;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

#### Temporary table

Similar solution with a temporary table:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM regexp_split_to_table(:'values', ',') v;

DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _val text;
BEGIN
   FOR _val IN
      TABLE tmp
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'v: %', _val;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Comment: Erwin, thank you so much for your answer! Would you mind taking a look at [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29000817/4660395) I had as well to comment on it's validity? It works, I'm just worried if it's proper/safe.

Comment: the do statement can be pretty formated with the help of `select format('multiline statement',[args]) as do \gset`

Answer (score 4):

Was able to take advantage of this solution:

- [Passing argument to a psql procedural script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076483/4660395)

Where I set the variable as such and retrieve it with `current_setting()`

```
\set values foo,bar,baz
SET vars.values TO :'values';

DO $$
DECLARE
    value  TEXT;
    values TEXT[] := string_to_array(current_setting('vars.values'), ',');
BEGIN
    FOREACH value IN ARRAY values LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'v: %', value;
    END LOOP;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: That works, too. Just like the other answer from Pavel. I wouldn't use a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `values` as variable names, even if that one's allowed in Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you! They're named differently in the code; I changed the names to value/values for this post.