# Is it possible to combine `-c` and `-v` in psql?

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

**Abstract**

Why this does not work:

```
$ psql -X -h localhost -d mydatabase -U postgres -v myschema=foo -c "SELECT :'myschema';"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SELECT :'myschema';
               ^
```

But this works as expected:

```
$ psql -X -h localhost -d mydatabase -U postgres -v myschema=foo

mydatabase=# SELECT :'myschema';
 ?column? 
----------
 foo
(1 row)
```

Is it possible to combine `-c` and `-v` in a `psql` call.

**Context**

I'm trying to execute a `DO` ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12082038/930271)) PostgreSQL statement with `psql -c` from a bash script, where I want to pass one of the `WHERE` conditions as a [psql variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES)

Something like this:

```
SCHEMA='foo'

! read -d '' sql_query << "EOF"
DO
$func$
BEGIN
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', 
   EXECUTE
   (SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || string_agg(oid::regclass::text, ', ') || ' CASCADE'
    FROM   pg_class
    WHERE  relkind = 'r'  -- only tables
    AND    relnamespace = :'myschema'::regnamespace
   );
END
$func$;    
EOF

psql -h localhost -U postgres -d mydatabase -v myschema="${SCHEMA}" -c "${sql_query}"
```

But it fails with a:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 9:     AND    relnamespace = :'myschema'::regnamespace
```

Trying to debug the problem I write just this simple query:

```
psql -v myschema=foo -h localhost -d mydatabase -U postgres -c "SELECT :myschema;"
ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SELECT :myschema
               ^
LOCATION:  scanner_yyerror, scan.l:1087
```

or variations of it like:

```
psql -v myschema="'foo'" -h localhost -d mydatabase -U postgres -c "SELECT :myschema;"
psql -v myschema 'foo' -h localhost -d mydatabase -U postgres -c "SELECT :myschema;"
psql -v myschema=foo -h localhost -d mydatabase -U postgres -c "SELECT :'myschema';"
```

and neither works.

So the question is. It's is possible to combine `-c` and `-v` in a `psql` call.

**DO statements and psql variables**

Thanks to the comments I discover that [a workaround is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28999217/930271) to mix `DO` statements and psql variables.

Or fix it at `bash` level. This is how I'm doing it:

```
SCHEMA='foo'

! read -d '' sql_query << EOF
DO
$func$
BEGIN
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', 
   EXECUTE
   (SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || string_agg(oid::regclass::text, ', ') || ' CASCADE'
    FROM   pg_class
    WHERE  relkind = 'r'  -- only tables
    AND    relnamespace = '${SCHEMA}'::regnamespace
   );
END
$func$;    
EOF

psql -h localhost -U postgres -d mydatabase -c "${sql_query}"
```

But the question still is how (if possible) psql variables can be used with `-c`

Comment: No. `do` body is just a string (dollar quoted) and it used as is, without psql variables substitution. Lets say it is same to `select 'foo :myschema bar';` or `select $str$foo :myschema bar$str$;` Just use bash variable substitution instead.

Comment: What about the non-`do` cases like `psql -v myschema=foo -h localhost -d mydatabase -U postgres -c "SELECT :'myschema';"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use variable set by psql meta-command inside of DO block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997527/use-variable-set-by-psql-meta-command-inside-of-do-block)

Comment: @Abelisto thanks for the research. It answers the concrete use case of the `DO` that anyway can be resolved escaping dollar quotes or other `bash` strategies, but still it does not answer why the simple `SELECT :myschema;` query with `-c` does not work.

Comment: Because after substitution it will be `SELECT foo;` (single quotes removed by psql while variable assigned). @thatotherguy already provide the possible solution. If you want to use variable inside string then it should be something like `select 'foo ' || :'myvar' || ' bar';`

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto I updated my question to clarify the points you mention. As you said theres is a bug it should be `SELECT :'myschema'` and not `SELECT :myschema;` but the broad question still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So the question is. It's is possible to combine -c and -v in a psql
> call.*

No, psql does not expand variables in queries passed on the command line.
It's implied in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) by the bit outlined in bold below:

> -c command
> --command=command
>
> Specifies that psql is to execute the given command string, command. This option can be repeated and combined in any order with
> the -f option. When either -c or -f is specified, psql does not read
> commands from standard input; instead it terminates after processing
> all the -c and -f options in sequence.
>
> command must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., **it contains no psql-specific features**), or a single backslash command.

Comment: Ouch. Shame on me. I read the doc but misinterpret (or unread) that bit of info. Thanks a lot.