# PostgreSQL script control structures

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have an sql script which copies data from a file:

```
--myscript.sql
\set file :dir 'data.csv'
copy data from :'file' csv;
```

and execute it with `psql` providing the `dir` variable

```
psql -v dir="D:\data\" -f myscript.sql
```

now I would like the `copy` command executed only if some other variable is let, e.g. `-v doit=`

Are there any script control structures available for this? Looking for something like

```
$if :{?doit}
copy data from :'file' csv;
$endif;
```

Have tried to wrap it by an anonymous block

```
do '
begin
    if ':{?doit}' then
        copy data from :'file' csv;
    end if;
end';
```

But it gives the error

```
Error: syntax error (approximate position "TRUE")
LINE 3:  if 'TRUE' then
             ^
```

Comment: I found related post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997527/use-variable-set-by-psql-meta-command-inside-of-do-block

Comment: So can you try concatenate into one line?

Comment: This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/29000817/5360898 solved it perfectly. Thanks for the directions!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

There were two issues there

1. psql variables cannot be directly substituted in `do` statements
   This can be solved by putting a psql variable into a server setting as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29000817/5360898)
2. the `copy` command does not accept any functions for the file path name, so the first solution won't work here.

I ended up formating the do block like this

```
select format('
begin
    if ''%s''=''t'' then
        copy rates from ''%s'' csv header delimiter E''\t'';
    end if;
end;',:{?doit},:'file') as do \gset
do :'do';
```

The `format` function lets us use a multiline string. The resulting string is then assigned to a new varialbe with the help of `\gset` and feed it to `do`.

Note: The format function formats 'TRUE' as 't', so we have to treat it as such.

Thanks to [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15603477/mark) for the directions.